# How to run expect script from remote server via ssh?

Tags: bash, expect

I have deployed an expect script on a remote server, which I want to run via ssh.

```
ssh user@host 'expect -d ./netopeer_expect.sh' (1)

user@host:~$ cat netopeer_expect.sh
#!/usr/bin/expect

set timeout 5
#spawn netopeer2-cli
spawn ./np2_multi_cli
expect ">"
send "listen --timeout 120\r"
expect "ru_id 0"
send "get-config -D=0 --source running --out /home/user/out.xml\r"
expect ">"
send "exit\r"
expect "$"
```

This code runs a modified version of the netopeer2-cli, which we call ./np2_multi_cli. This netopeer2-cli have an own shell and a prompt like >. It works fine when I do it in two steps

```
ssh user@host
expect -d ./netopeer_expect.sh (2)
```

However, the message

```
send "get-config -D=0 --source running --out /home/user/out.xml\r"
```

is cut and is sent as,

```
send "-D=0 --source running --out /home/user/out.xml\r"
```

From running (1) with the -d argument I see this,

> expect: does "\u001b[6n" (spawn_id exp3) match glob pattern ">"? no

When I try to match the first >. When I instead try to run (2), it looks as it should,

> expect: does "> " (spawn_id exp4) match glob pattern ">"? yes

I run bash and it seems as if there are some encoding issues regarding the > character. Any idea how to deal with this?

BR
Patrik

Comment: @KamilCuk Looks as if it is ascii, `user@host:~$ file -bi netopeer_expect.sh
text/plain; charset=us-ascii`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did some investigation and found out why `ssh -t` makes a difference in [patrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56544774/900078). See the following examples:

[image]

According to Expect [manual](https://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expect.1.html):

> Internally,  `spawn`  uses a pty, **initialized the same way as the user's tty**.

With `-t`, ssh would allocate a pty (the same type as the local `$TERM`) for the remote session, then `expect` allocates a pty of the same type.

Without `-t`, ssh would not allocate pty for the remote session, and `expect` uses the (default?) `dumb` tty which is **not fully featured**. As a "workaround", we can explicityly set the `TERM` var (e.g. `set env(TERM) vt100`) before `spawn`.

---

Here's the command I used. Just for easy copy-and-paste.

```
[STEP 101] # cmd=' "spawn -noe bash -c {echo TERM=\$TERM | grep --color TERM}; expect eof" '
[STEP 102] #
[STEP 103] # ssh 127.0.0.1 expect -c "$cmd"
TERM=dumb
[STEP 104] # ssh -t 127.0.0.1 expect -c "$cmd"
TERM=linux
Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.
[STEP 105] #
[STEP 106] # cmd=' "set env(TERM) vt100; spawn -noe bash -c {echo TERM=\$TERM | grep --color TERM}; expect eof" '
[STEP 107] # ssh 127.0.0.1 expect -c "$cmd"
TERM=vt100
[STEP 108] #
```

Comment: Thanks! I will make this the accepted answer, as it is much more complete than mine.

Answer (score 3):

Looks as if I made a faulty call when I was running ssh. I forced pseudo terminal allocation it went fine,

```
ssh -t -t erusim@147.214.83.188 'expect -d ./netopeer_expect.sh'
```

Comment: I was about to suggest this. Looks like that cli tool relies on the tty.

Comment: @pynexj I am not really sure, I got some weird prompt errors without -t. Assuming you run ssh without allocating tty, would this not make you run everything via stdout and stdin? So that expect cannot locate a pty? Or am I wrong? Thankful for comments, objections, as I would be happy to learn more about this.